# How to know that the dragged files from specific file extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making my own dropzone and I want to do an action while specific file extension dragging, I found that `onDragEnter` can't access file types, `onDrop` only can make that.

But I found a library that makes what I want to do, I tried hard to know from the source code how they do it but I fail. here is the link of the code

https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/#!/Accepting%20specific%20file%20types/5

Answer (score 2):

Actually the file type is available, I don't know how react dropzone does it, but you can access the type via `DragEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].type`, `items` is the array of items being dragged so you can access the others via `items[1]` etc.

```js
$('div').on('dragover',function(e){
console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].type);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>dropzone</div>
```

Comment: One thing I have noticed as I'm putting a React drag and drop uploader together - for some reason, the "type" attribute is an empty string when the dropped files are fonts. No idea why though.

Comment: for me the `event` does not have a `originalEvent`. For whom this is not working try: `e.dataTransfer.items[0].type`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are right that the `onDragEnter` doesn't give you this information, however you can get the information from the `onDragOver`.

To do this with React, I guess the easiest is to use the ref callback to get the element where you want to drop to (or use the events on the element directly).

```
setTargetDropZone( element ) {
  if (this.dropZone) {
    // remove any previous attached event
    this.dropZone.removeEventListener('dragover', this.onDragOver );
  }
  // update the local field with the new element
  this.dropZone = element;
  if (!this.dropZone) {
    return;
  }
  // if it is not null attach the new event
  this.dropZone.addEventListener( 'dragover', this.onDragOver );
}
```

Somewhere you would have to define which file types you want to accept, and then you have to handle the incoming data to filter it.

```
const { fileTypes = null } = this.props;
const { items } = e.dataTransfer;
let dropCount = items.length;

// if it is restricted, count how many actually match
if (fileTypes) {
  // items is not an array, so you could use Array.from here
  dropCount = Array.from( items ).filter( item => fileTypes.some( type => item.type.includes( type ) ) ).length;
}
```

So if you combine this code, in the end, you could end up with something like this

```js
const { Component } = React;

const DropState = {
  'All': '0',
  'No': '1',
  'Some': '2',
  '0': 'All',
  '1': 'No',
  '2': 'Some'
};

class DropZone extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dropState: DropState.All,
      dropCount: 0
    };
    this.setTargetDropZone = this.setTargetDropZone.bind( this );
  }
  onDragOver = e => {
    const { fileTypes = null } = this.props;
    const { items } = e.dataTransfer;
    let dropCount = items.length;
    
    if (fileTypes) {
      dropCount = Array.from( items ).filter( item => fileTypes.some( type => item.type.includes( type ) ) ).length;
    }
  
    this.setState( {
      dropCount,
      dropState: dropCount === items.length ? DropState.All : dropCount === 0 ? DropState.No : DropState.Some
    } );
  } 
  setTargetDropZone( element ) {
    if (this.dropZone) {
      this.dropZone.removeEventListener('dragover', this.onDragOver );
    }
    this.dropZone = element;
    if (!this.dropZone) {
      return;
    }
    this.dropZone.addEventListener( 'dragover', this.onDragOver );
  }
  render() {
    const { dropState, dropCount } = this.state;
    const { placeholder = 'Drop some files here' } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <div ref={this.setTargetDropZone} style={{border: 'solid #a0a0a0 1px' }}>
      { dropCount > 0 && <span>{ `${DropState[dropState]} will be accepted (${dropCount})` }</span> }
      { dropCount === 0 && placeholder }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const container = document.querySelector('#container');

ReactDOM.render( <DropZone fileTypes={ ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ] } />, container );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```